# How to install a valid certificate for CUPS HTTPS admin server

Tags: ssl, cups, clearos

I am running ClearOS release 7.5.0 (Final). I have installed the cups print server. It provides a web interface to control it at `https://192.168.1.1:631/`. But when I put this address into Chrome, it always complains that the certificate is invalid.

I also have LetsEncrypt installed, which I use to create certificates for some external-facing web sites on the same machine.

Is it possible to use a LetsEncrypt certificate in cups, or to convince Chrome that the cups certificate is OK?